# Kubernetes Heapster not working

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I installed kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu VM
I also installed heapster.
But when I do

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
```

I am getting error:

```
--2016-11-04 14:44:41--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/ [following]
--2016-11-04 14:44:42--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/
Reusing existing connection to 127.0.0.1:8080.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-11-04 14:44:42 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following URL which is without "proxy" works for me:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following while querying through proxy

- `/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:heapster/api/v1/model/namespaces/`
- `/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/api/v1/model/namespaces/`
- `/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:heapster/api/v1/model/namespaces/`

This specifies a port and some suffix for a heapster listener. I assume that you really get a response, but the response is a real 404 from heapster because a request to root is not being processed.

All the suffixes from heapster's model may be found here: https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/model.md